# Is there an OpenStreetMap label layer?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, labeling, quickmapservices

Is there an OSM label layer available? This [same question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41002/is-there-a-layer-type-that-supports-just-labels) was asked 7 years ago. I neither see such a layer in the OpenLayers plugin nor QuickMapServices.

I'm working on a project with a 50% transparent layer over OSM monochrome. It would look better to have the OSM labels over my layer, with the basemap free of labels.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this example of Wilmington, IL United States?
Which is using vector data rather than raster images.

[image]

This is using the QGIS Plugin **OSMDownloader** available in QGIS plugins

1. Select your area of interest
2. Save to a folder
3. It will download the data in the format for QGIS and set the layers

The Styles will be applied and you can then tinker with the settings and rules for labelling items of interest - like buildings here.

update after comment:
[image]
Remove all the zoom level except 1 and switch of the symbol (right at the bottom) but the labels will remain active.

Comment: Very handy. Following up, I want to see only the labels of the polygons. I've deleted all the downloaded layers except osm multpolygons. And in all of the Building polys I've set the fill style and the stroke style to No Brush and No Pen, respectively. I still see building outlines at all zoom levels?

Comment: @Pfalbaum have updated the answer with a screenshot of just the labels displaying with building symbol/style switched off but labels remain on.